# Detecting BitTorrent across a home, wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, bittorrent

We live in Germany and have just received a letter from a law firm indicating that we have downloaded/watched a movie using BitTorrent - We definitely haven't. However, we have a self contained flat within our house that we rent out - and they have access to our wireless router.

Before, I talk with them I want to see if BitTorrent (or something of that nature) is running across our wireless router. Can anyone provide me with some advice as to the right way to go (I'm certainly no expert in this field)?

Thank you.

Comment: This is more appropriate for SuperUser as it's a home network so I've flagged it for migration.

Comment: What kind of router do you have at home?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your router, you can put custom software on your wireless router, e.g. dd-wrt, that can block p2p protocols or you can block websites containing torrent, p2p etc in the config so that they can't access torrent sites.

With custom software on the router, you can do a lot of nifty things, like monitoring and analysing traffic.

With or without the monitoring set up, I would talk to everybody who has access and explain the situation and that monitoring is or will be set up and illegal torrents are not accepted (with or without consequences). The most strict measures that you can take is to cut off their internet access and let them pay for their own internet.

But not all torrents are illegal. For example many Linux downloads are offered via bittorrent, as well many other free things, and e.g. BTSync, a software tool to sync files across devices with the torrent protocol. If you block those things, you won't be able to make use of them and if you monitor traffic, you won't be able to distinguish between legal and illegal downloads.

Also if you have all your restrictions set up, it's fairly easy to circumvent them with the use of VPN connections for example, a perfectly legal tool as well. So in my mind, you're best of with the policies and if you still can't trust your renters, you just have to kick them out and find new ones.

I'm not sure how the policies are in Germany, but usually the person who is responsible for the connection is blamed for illegal activity. You can then sue your renters for any damages occured if it appears to be them. It may be good if you can find some legal advise on it to be sure.

Another thing you have to be careful about, is that it's happened before that malicious people send out such emails to extort money from (innocent) people. People are afraid for legal actions and are eager to pay a settlement outside of court.... Be weary and do some investigation on the company who sent the letter as well! If something doesn't seem right, go and report it!